# Android Studio & Constraint Layout Editor Problems

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, android-constraintlayout

I have watched numerous videos, including Google's own, and i'm really struggling with ConstraintLayout, it simply doesn't work for me, like it works in the online videos.

When I drop a textview onto the constraint layout editor, it jumps to the top right of the form.  In the demo videos, it stays where it's dropped, and it's easy for those people to set up the relationships by dragging handles.  For me, It's all up in the top right, and I can only get to 2 of the handles.

It gets worse if I then drop two more text views into the form, they are all now all the same size and all overlapped at the top.  Whenever I use constraint layout, I end up tearing my hair out, and then giving up and going back to an older layout.

I really want to use constraintlayout, but clearly I am missing something really obvious here, but I can't figure out what.

Comment: Write everything with your hands and you will get used to it very quickly. To begin with, it was strange for me too.

Comment: don't think what you've posted here, we can help with. if there's a bug or something wrong with your IDE, you'll have to reinstall it or troubleshoot it yourself, at least to the point where we can recreate it, otherwise you'll have to show some code or something others can recreate here

Comment: I would also suggest against using directly the layout editor. Instead you can directly type the XML which is much more easier. The layout editor is not that remarkable if I am being honest.

Comment: I don't think it's a bug, I have never been able to get it to work across any version of Android Studio, and I even did a clean install.  I figured I am missing something, and must be doing something wrong, as in it's current way of working, it's not usable at all.

Answer (score 0):

Yes the drag and drop doesn't work well. For me I just use several steps to add a new view:

```
1. drag new view to the end of the view list window (not on the design view! design view will add unnecessary properties and is not clean)
2. select the new view, and name it! name is very important to constraint layout.
3. set the layout_constraint_xxx attributes from the property window
```

then it goes to the expected places.

Answer (score 0):

Try disabling the experimental render engine and re enable it again